# Space separated integers to array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm new to C, and I have an assignment where I get an input of `n` space separated integers, and `q` integers separated by new lines. I would like to save the `n` integers in an array `a`, and the `q` integers in another array `m`.

This is my code so far and it works as expected for `m`, but the elements in `a` are pretty random. How can I save the space separated integers into an array?

```
int main() {

    // The code
    int n, q;
    int a[n];
    int m[q];

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<q; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &m[i]);
    }

    // Troubleshooting
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i=0; i<q; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", m[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example when I input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I get:

```
4 5 3 4 5 6 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Do you  only want to parse valid input or detect invalid input also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but when i run your code i get segmentation error because instead  of:

```
    int n, q;
    int a[n];
    int m[q];

   scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
```

You should first read n,q and then declare a[n],m[q] like this:

```
int n, q;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
int a[n];
int m[q];
```

I tried running your code giving 6 6 for the first scanf so n=6,q=6
and after that as your example i gave input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

and it printed right.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `scanf`. [`scanf` is notoriously hard to use](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), and it's particularly wrong for your situation because it will not distinguish between different types of whitespace (spaces versus newlines).

Instead, you should read input line-by-line using `fgets` and then parse each line using `sscanf` or `strtok`.